# Prove that the filter is stable, causal and minimum phase

Tags: continuous-signals, laplace-transform, stability, causality, minimum-phase

I have a system which has the following transfer function
$$H(s)=\frac{\beta + s}{s^{2} + 2\alpha s + \beta^{2}}$$
where $\beta = \sqrt{\omega^{2} + \alpha^{2}}$ and $\alpha>0$.

This system, as already discussed in a [dsp question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83773/study-the-stability-of-hs-frac-beta-ss2-2-alpha-s-beta2) is stable. How can I check the other two properties?

**EDIT**

If a random (wide-sense stationary) process $n(t)$ passes through a time-invariant filter $h(\tau)$, then the autocorrelation function is
$$R_{n^\prime}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} R_{n}(t-\tau+\tau^\prime) h(\tau) h(\tau^\prime) d \tau d \tau^\prime$$
For white noise input, $R_{n}(t)=\delta(t)$ and
$$
    R_{n^\prime}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  h(\tau-t) h(\tau) d \tau 
$$
The power spectrum of the output is the Laplace transform of $R_{n^\prime}(t)$ and it is possible to prove that
$$    S_{n^\prime}(s)= H(-s) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  h(\tau)  e^{-s \tau}d \tau=H(-s)  H(s) 
$$
In my case I have $H(s)=\frac{\beta + s}{s^{2} + 2\alpha s + \beta^{2}}$. I would like to prove that the filter is stable, causal and minimum phase.

Comment: What are your thoughts about this? If you know the definition of "minimum phase", what problems did you encounter when trying to find out if the given system satisfies the respective conditions? A good answer to that question should be quite long because given only the expression for the transfer function, you can't say anything about stability or causality. You need more information.

Comment: I've added an answer to your [other question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83773/4298), clarifying a few points that are also relevant to this question.

Comment: What makes a filter “unique”? Stable, causal, and minimum phase I get, but what is “unique”?

Comment: And -- since this looks like homework -- what work have you done so far to answer it on your own?

Comment: Thanks to all. I edited my post

Answer (score 3):

In general, the algebraic expression of a transfer function alone doesn't uniquely describe a single system. For the example in your question with two complex conjugate poles in the left-half plane, the given transfer function describes two systems: one is causal and stable, the other one is non-causal and unstable.

[image: Illustration of ROC for each case.]

A complete (external) description of an LTI system is given by the transfer function **and** the corresponding region of convergence (ROC). For a causal system, the ROC is a right half-plane. Since the ROC *to the right* of the two poles includes the imaginary axis, the corresponding causal system is stable. Since the ROC *to the left* of the two poles does not include the imaginary axis, the corresponding non-causal system is unstable.

So, *assuming* that the given transfer function is meant to describe a causal system, BIBO (bounded-input, bounded-output)-stability follows immediately.

For answering the question if that causal system is a minimum-phase system, you just have to ask if it is possible to invert the system by a causal and stable system. If that is the case, the system is a minimum-phase system, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: Thx @PeterK. for the nice plots!

Comment: You're welcome!  I like having some pics when ROCs are talked about, so I thought it'd add to your excellent answer.